# How to remove a TreeItem from a Tree in java SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I am using java SWT for an application development.

There is a SWT Tree with some child nodes in the tool and I want to delete some of them. I tried using remove() and removeAll() methods but it does not delete the item completely. It leaves behind a space for TreeItem.

[image]

Comment: Is the Tree + TreeItem you are using or the JFace TreeViewer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t73267.html), you should use `item.dispose()` on the treeitem you want to completely remove.

Answer (score 5):

`TreeItem` is a descendant of `Widget` which contains the [dispose()](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTreeItem.html) method. According to documentation:

> Disposes of the operating system resources associated with the
>   receiver and all its descendants. After this method has been invoked,
>   the receiver and all descendants will answer true when sent the
>   message isDisposed(). Any internal connections between the widgets in
>   the tree will have been removed to facilitate garbage collection. This
>   method does nothing if the widget is already disposed.

So `treeItem.dispose()` will work.